# Verify SharePoint Restore

Tags: sharepoint, restore, back

I have created a new SharePoint 2007 MOSS Intranet. Our admin people are purchasing backup/restore software and I will eventually have to verify a restore of the farm backup they create. Has anyone got some suggestions on a best practice for this? Ours is a small 2-server farm built with VMWare VMs on SAN. How will I know that the restored version is a duplicate of the original in every way and what should I look out for?

Comment: Wouldn't the original be broken if you needed to restore? 
how would you do a compare? I've never had any problems with the restore. P.S. We use DPM and/ or Content Database only backup / restore (for small deployments)

Comment: What I'm getting at is, is there some kind of checklist? I have done it with STSADM but I have not created a process to verify the restore. I don't want to find out months down the road that a document library has gone missing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to the remarks:

There's no checklist. The problem is the dynamic nature of SharePoint. Team Sites come and go, as do documents and libraries. Who's to say one of your users didn't delete a document library and then you think after a restore something is missing.

I think the best bet would be to require your users to do a quick scan after a restore, see if they miss anything major, like sites or libraries that are supposed to be there. You yourself could have a "homemade" checklist that you follow to check if all major features deployed by you (features, timerjobs etc.) are still there.

Comment: Thanks for your input Colin (+1 and marked as answer). I'd like to make the point though that the site is locked down during a backup/restore (either manually with setsitelock, or automatically depending on which patch is applied), so nobody is adding anything. I still think that this is being overlooked as a serious admin consideration and there is a need for either a tool and/or process to guarantee the fidelity of the restore - should not need 3rd party software for something as basic as this :-)